# How to customize graph title and subtitle

Tags: highcharts

I want to customize my charts mostly the title and subtitle like the attached image. Please suggest!
Also I like to add gradient in the area charts.
Is it possible to design chart like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set useHTML as true, and in the title text i.e define two divs (left / right content) with correct CSS styles.

```
text: '<div class="lhsTitle">My custom title</div><div class="rhsTitle">Right content</div>',
```

CSS

```
.lhsTitle {
    float:left;
}
.rhsTitle {
    float:right
}

.highcharts-title {
    width:80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/BETBk/

Comment: How can I give the underline.

Comment: you can use border-bottom:1px solid gray; in highcharts-title div.

Comment: I would like to know another thing, i.e. if I want to hide the print and download button, then what I need to change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can ovewrite exporing options. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting

Answer (score 1):

You can add a linear gradient to the series with the following snippet of code:

```
... //inside Highcharts chart object

series : [{
    name : "Series name",
    type : "area",
    fillColor : {
        linearGradient : [0, 0, 0, 300],
        stops : [
            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3]],
            [1, 'rgba(2,0,0,0)']
        ]
    },
    data: [...]
}]
```

as shown in the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/aNtnm/